# Process name post killing

Tags: linux, process, out-of-memory

I am getting OOM error and killed process error in logs. In the logs, I can see the process ID which has been killed by kernel but not able to find out which process is actually been killed.

Can we get the process name through process ID although process is already killed and not running on the server?

Comment: Please provide more information. Which log and which Linux distro and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no reliable way to know exactly what process was killed by pid, process ids are assigned by the scheduler as it loads them to the task queue , so is very likely that one process can have different ids depending on how and when they are loaded.

However, it is possible that some task helper process such as  systemd|sysvinit|etc..., had logged the process list with their respective pid and timestamp. so you could track the culprit process with those logs. but we'll need more info. As suggested by ***coffeMug***